# How to make a command that runs Python a script in Windows command line?

Tags: python, command-line, environment-variables

## Background:

I'm using Windows. I know some of programming with python. I don't know much about `batch`, which I think I might need to do what I want.

I will show a example so it becomes more clear what I'm trying to do.

## Example:

When using `git`, after you install it, you can call the `git` command from anywhere of your computer, you can execute `git` commands, like `git init` and this will create a git file in your current folder.

I don't know exactly how git works or what language they use but I want to do the same thing, create my own command that I can execute from anywhere in my computer after I *"install"* my program.

## What I'm trying to do:

I want to make my own command and when I call it, it executes a python script.
*e.g.*
I install my program and it creates a command called `myprogram` and when I type `myprogram` in the command line, it's like if I typed `python myprogram.py`. And `myprogram -someargument` would be the same as `python myprogram.py -someargument`.

## What I tried until now:

I'm searched for **How to make a environment variable that runs Python script?** but I never get exactly what I want, is always something like *How do I set environment variable using Python script?*.

Maybe I'm making the wrong question and the result I want are not showing?

**I'm looking for a explanation on how to do this or at least a tutorial/guide.**

## Edit 1:

As UnholySheep said in the comments, it's not *environment variable*, its commands, so I changed the question even does what I want to know is the same thing.

Comment: Those aren't environment variables, they are command line programs that are added to the `PATH` variable

Comment: @UnholySheep i found [this](http://www.correlatedsolutions.com/support/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/85/1/running-python-scripts-from-anywhere-under-windows) but it doesn't answer my question, should I edit my question?

Comment: Yes, please edit it to show what you have tried and explain why it doesn't work for you

Comment: Know that it's not called environment variables and it's actually a command helped my alot, I'm going to edit the question and post the solution that I just found, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Files you need:

First you need a python script (obviously) so I created a file called `myprogram.py` that have this simple line:

```
print("This should be from a command")
```

After you need to make a batch file, in my case I used a `.cmd` file called `myprogram.cmd` that have:

```
@ECHO OFF
python_directory\python.exe python_script_directory\myprogram.py %*
```

## Configurations to make:

You need to set in `PATH` environment variable the location of the batch file `batch_file_directory\myprogram.cmd`

And now if you execute in the command line `myprogram` it will print *This should be from a command*.

You can also use `.exe` or `.bat` files.